# Understanding "&" (and) bitwise operation

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I am trying to understand the bitwise operations in the next algorithm. The code itself converts a number to hexadecimal representation.

Could you please explain (*the why*) of the logic where **n & 15** yields the correct index location from the chars string?

For the **>>>** operation, what I understand is that will remove the most right-hand side digit preserving the negative sign, is that correct?

```
static String toHex(int n) {
    final String chars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (n != 0) {
        sb.insert(0, chars.charAt(n & 15));
        n >>>= 4;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n & 15));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is not what I am asking. I am not asking how to convert to Hexadecimal. My question is about the logic behind "n & 15". I know there are already built-in functions that can perform the hex conversion but this is not the question.

Comment: 15 (binary: 0000 0000 0000 1111) is a mask that sets all bits in the result from `n & 15` to 0, with the exception of the lower 4 bits. The result will be a number between 0 and 15, which reads the corresponding character from `chars` as an index.

Comment: This function outputs the digits backwards.

Comment: You asked how a bitwise operation works. **Print** the value (in binary) before and after the operation, and the operation should be obvious.

Comment: @API_1024 There are only two things that matter in your question: `n & 15` and `n >>>= 4`. You should focus on what those two operations do. Someone has already explained exactly [what they do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67774675/2970947).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 15 = 1111 in binary, the result of **n & 15** will have the bits of n in the last 4 positions, and 0's everywhere else. So it's a fancier way of a modulo operation **n % 16**.

The **n >>>= 4** will remove the last 4 bits, move all remaining bits 4 places to the right, and add 4 0's in front. So that's just a fancy way of doing the integer division **n / 16**.

For negative numbers, it's actually different than the normal modulo or division, because the **& 15** will always give a positive number, and the **>>>= 4** will also always give a positive number.